# SettingWithCopyWarning on Column Creation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a moving average column for my data called 'mv_avg'. I'm getting a SettingWithCopyWarning that I have been unable to fix. I could suppress the warning, but I cannot figure out where in my code I am creating a copy, and I want to utilize best practices. I've created a generalizable example below to illustrate the problem.

```
data = {'category' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'value' : [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_a = df.loc[df['category'] == 'a']
df_a['mv_avg'] = df_a['value'].rolling(window=2).mean()
```

This returns:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I've also tried the more verbose version:

```
df_a.loc[: , 'mv_avg'] = df_a.loc[:,'value'].rolling(window=2).mean()
```

but I get the same error. What is the best way to accomplish this without the warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create a copy using .copy()

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'category' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'value' : [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_a = df.loc[df['category'] == 'a'].copy()
df_a['mv_avg'] = df_a['value'].rolling(window=2).mean()
```

or you can use an indexer  such has :

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'category' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'value' : [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
indexer = df[df['category'] == 'a'].index
df_a = df.loc[indexer, :]
df_a['mv_avg'] = df_a['value'].rolling(window=2).mean()
```

Comment: In case of explicit copying (`df_a = df.loc[df['category'] == 'a'].copy()`), is the data copied twice (first by boolean indexing and then by `.copy()`) ?

Comment: @Aivar, it is unclear, it may or may not be a double copy. ( this is coming from an issue I raised on the pandas github)

Answer (score 2):

Here are three options

1. Ignore/filter the warning; in this case it is spurious as you are deliberately assigning to a filtered DataFrame.
2. If you are done with `df`, you could `del` it, which will prevent the warning, because `df_a`will no longer hold a reference to `df`.
3. Take a copy as in the other answer